# What is this type of sound effect called?

Tags: terminology, sound-effects

There is a sound typically associated with a bright flash of light, which starts with a lower whirring noise, then breaks into a higher pitched sound. What is that type of sound called? I'm not sure how to begin searching for that, so a typical name for it would be very helpful.

It's something similar to what occurs at 0:41 in [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94S0FFk_has) ([here's a link to a few seconds beforehand](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94S0FFk_has#t=35s)), where Naruto 6 tails transforms into Kyuubei in *Naruto Generations*.

Comment: Could you show us a youtube video which has this sound effect and what time it occurs, or relate to us a game that has this sound effect and at what point it occurs (e.g. the noise of a flashbang, etc)?

Comment: A klaxon alarm? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGloWW0-XkE

Comment: Thanks for that! Good question, too! Do you mean from the instant the screen blurs (and just before we see his eyes) to the explosion? It might not actually have a specific name, but it could fit into a more general category which _does_ have a name.

Comment: This is mostly the sound I'm hearing: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE_giIrEqm8 I searched for "anime sword slice sound effect"

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Yes, and just before that, where a pillar of blue chakra rises up around him, though they seem to have it in the reverse order of what I had in mind (they have the higher pitched sound first, then the lower pitched whirring before we see his eyes).

Comment: Honestly, unless it's a found sound, something you'd hear in real life, sound designers tend to speak to each other using terms like, "whoOOOoooOOooozzsshshsshWEEEEEING!"

Comment: @michael.bartnett I'd hope you were joking, but somehow I doubt that you are. That being the case, how would I even begin to search sound banks for that?

Comment: @Fibericon If you're ever at GDC, hit up the AudioDev SIG, and you'll find a cadre of composers and sound designers begging you to stop trying to describe what you want and just use mouth noises and movie references. Only slightly exaggerating ;)

Comment: @michael.bartnett Fibericon, what he says is the truth. My ex is a foley artist and laments that one of the worst parts of the job is the lack of searchability due to sounds not having a real descriptive vocabulary. The closest you can get is using musical terms for note [texture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_%28music%29) along with [ADSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_%28music%29#ADSR_envelope). It is a mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't really think there's a name for either the "blue chakra rising" or the "zoom in on eyes" effect. From what I can tell, the first is a waveform (maybe saw or triangle) that has a high pass filter with the cutoff frequency being swept up.

The second sounds like it uses a multi oscillator with a triangle/saw waveform and a noise wave which again uses a high pass filter with the cutoff frequency being swept up. The noise wave creates the sort of "whoosh" windy sound.

I am by no means an expert, but that's what it sounds like just for starters (along with a bunch of other effects, reverb, compression etc).

To demonstrate this go here: http://www.bfxr.net/

Change the wave to saw or triangle, set the "frequency" to low, the "frequency cutoff" all the way to the left and slowly increase the "frequency slide" towards the right.

Comment: Not only is that a good set of instructions for recreating the sound, that's an excellent resource!